# Bootstrap Container Size And Alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, size, containers

Okay so first off here's the link to the page I'm having troubles with: http://brysonlinden.net/roster.html

I want the text box with all the players names to be the exact same size as the jumbotron and I'm unsure how to do this with Bootstrap 3.0.

If you could take a look at the source code and tell me what to change that would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="well col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">

                <!-- ADAM MOFFAT -->
                <div class="row user-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="pics/players/default.png" height="50px" width="50px" alt="User Pic">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <strong>Adam Moffat</strong><br>
                        <span class="text-muted">Player Position: Defensive End</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 dropdown-user" data-for=".amoffat">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row user-infos amoffat">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Adam Moffat</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                        <img class="img-circle" src="pics/players/default.png" height="100px" width="100px" alt="User Pic">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                                        <img class="img-circle" src="pics/players/default.png" height="100px" width="100px" alt="User Pic">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                                        <strong>Player Information</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <dl>
                                            <dt>Player Number:</dt>
                                                <dd></dd>
                                            <dt>Player Position:</dt>
                                                <dd></dd>
                                            <dt>Height & Weight:</dt>
                                                <dd></dd>
                                            <dt>High School:</dt>
                                                <dd></dd>
                                        </dl>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                        <strong>Player Information</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <table class="table table-user-information">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Player Number:</td>
                                                    <td>#97</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Player Position:</td>
                                                    <td>Defensive End</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Height & Weight:</td>
                                                    <td>6'4", 215 lbs.</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>High School:</td>
                                                    <td>Holy Trinity CSS</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <strong>Offensive Statistics</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <table class="table table-user-information">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Pass Attempts:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Passes Made:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Passing Yards:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Passing Touchdowns:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Pass Interceptions:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Attempts:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Yards:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Touchdowns:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <strong>Defensive Statistics</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <table class="table table-user-information">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Tackles:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Assists:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Sacks:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Interceptions:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <strong>Receiving Statistics</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <table class="table table-user-information">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Attempts:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Yards:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Rush Touchdowns:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Receives:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Receiving Yards:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Receiving Touchdowns:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <strong>Kicking Statistics</strong>
                                        <br>
                                        <table class="table table-user-information">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Field Goal Attempts:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Field Goals Made:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Field Goal Longest:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Point After Touchdown Attempts:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Point After Touchdowns Made:</td>
                                                    <td>0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You should show us the code you've tried.

Comment: @AaronHall edited and added it in

Comment: @BrysonJayLinden Could you elaborate the question please ?